# How to implement OIDC (Open Id connect) server with OWIN

Tags: oauth-2.0, owin, openid-connect

I want to create OIDC server , went through too many links but couldn't found out a way to build OIDC server with OWIN Middle ware.

Note: I have already created a OAuth authorization server with the help of OWIN Middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The development of a provider is not one of highest priority scenarios for the OIDC OWIN middleware. If you are planning to create your own provider because you need customization, I would recommend picking up open source products like identityServer - see https://github.com/IdentityServer. If you are doing it as a learning experience, then I have not much advice to you - in fact, the more advice you get the less you will learn in the exercise... Anyway, if you need inspiration you can take a look at https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server

Comment: Thanks Vittorio . I have been able to successfully create  OAuth authorization server with help of Microsoft Owin OAuth middleware. Recently I came across OIDC specifications , and seems like enterprises are moving towards it (my point of interest is UserInfo endpoint) .  I am pretty sure that people would like to see OIDC provider as a part of Microsoft OWIN middleware list.